# How to use SVN without a server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

the idea is to use SVN (Tortoise) but, the thing is I dont have and dont want to use a server, cuz this will be used with only one person, is a college project.

I have an old computer that I could use to make a server, the idea is to use it like a server.  What documentation should I read, or what should I do to make it happen?...

Comment: If you want to do it the easy way, just grab VisualSVN Server; http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/

Comment: the server can be on the client computer.

Comment: Didn't know that was possible.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use [git](http://git-scm.com/) instead of svn for this.

Comment: Why not use a version control system designed to work without a server like Git, Bazaar, or Mercurial?

Comment: Ok, I want to let you know guys that I found a solution to my problem, I'm using Bitbucket and TortoiseHG and everything works just fine! Thx to all of you guys for the support and ideas.

Comment: @Daniel: the only difference here would be the path of the repository. Oh, and the tools: TortoiseSVN is excellent.

Answer (score 22):

You can access the repository using file:// protocol so you will only need Tortoise SVN installed and nothing else. See this question in FAQ: [Is it possible to use TortoiseSVN without a server?](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#noserver)

You can even have the repository in the usb device so that you can take the source with you and work on in from other computers.

Comment: I kept my (CVS) repo on a USB stick until I found it had been corrupted -- nothing too disastrous with CVS, maybe not so good with SVN! The thing is to always keep backups of the repo.

Comment: USB sticks have terrible I/O and the data can corrupt at any time especially with something like SVN on it.

Comment: Rather than a USB stick, has anyone considered using Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTE5OTIxOTk5) as a location for an svn repo? First two GB are free. Or if you're just not wanting to deal with the hassle of your own SVN server, you can get a free account at http://beanstalkapp.com/ and do your SVN there.

Comment: @jasonmp85 - actually I am using dropbox myself.

Answer (score 21):

1. Install [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net), right-click on a folder, choose [Create Repository Here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-create-tortoisesvn)
2. Right click on another folder, choose SVN Checkout, and specify the folder from step 1 above for the URL Repository. The first folder is your repository and the second -- is the working copy.

Comment: And, can I do that using a local server (an old PC converted to server)?

Comment: I thought you said "the thing is I dont have and dont want to use a server, cuz this will be used with only one person, is a college project." damit?

Comment: Yes.

Let me ask you something, let say I have tortoise installed on my computer, and I'm doing this project with a friend, can he commit something when my pc is on, and use my pc like a server?, if so, can I do the same thing?

Thx.

Comment: Btw, I cant choose SVN CO and point to my folder like you said, cuz I dont have an URL, only a path to my folder.. and Tortoise ask me for an URL.

Comment: Ok, I got it working :) I googled it and I realize I have to use file:/// something.

Ok now, my last question, how can I provide an URL to my friend so he can commit and update like I can right now?

Comment: Assuming your friend and you are on the same local network, you would need to setup a network share so he can see the repository folder. Then he would then map that share as a local "drive" X and use URL like file://X:/blah/yada/repository. But this is a hack, and won't work over Internet, so you should really setup an SVN server if you want to work with other people. Or get yourself a free SVN hosting account, for example on codebasehq.com

Answer (score 6):

Access your repository using `file://` or, alternatively, use svnserve. From [Svnserve Based Server](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html):

> Subversion includes Svnserve - a lightweight stand-alone server which uses a custom protocol over an ordinary TCP/IP connection. It is ideal for smaller installations, or where a full blown Apache server cannot be used.

The mentioned link provides installation instructions (actually, svnserve is part of subversion, there is nothing special to install). You can learn more in the official [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use an old workstation as an SVN server, I strongly recomend [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). Its free and dead simple to install. I have a workstation at home running it myself.

But if you are going to be the only one using it, and only from one workstation, then go with file:// protocol answer from Giorgi.

Comment: Now you mention it, I have and old computer that Im planning to use like a server, I'll install it some Linux distro and then an SVN server I guess, so, I'll try VisualSVN Server I think.

Comment: VisualSVN is actually for Windows XP+. I haven't tried to install and configure SVN server on Linux so I can't comment on how difficult that may be.

Comment: Interesting, so, I will install that VisualSVN Server, I'll read the documentation.

Comment: Ok, I've already tryied it out, and.. no, it's useless to me cuz svnclient is based on Visual Studio and I'm using Flex as IDE... so.

Comment: You're confusing two products. VisualSVN Server is a stand alone SVN Server. You can use any SVN client with it. There is also another product called VisualSVN, which is a Visual Studio add-in built on top of TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

Using [git](http://git-scm.com/) is a perfect solution for your problem. It is an distributed version control system and ideal for one person project.

You can also use your computer as a server without any installation.