# Setting up SVN locally?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

While working on local projects, you can't get back to the state of file that was 1 day ago or 1 month ago. So it would be great if we could use SVN for local projects too.

Does anyone know how to setup svn locally to keep projects' files versioned?

By local, I mean I should be able to version files with `file://` or `http://localhost/projectName` with wamp installed.

---

FYI, I am using windows 7.

Comment: See [can we set up svn server on a local computer without any network access?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/142123)

Comment: I would recommend VisualSVN http://www.visualsvn.com/server/ This is what I use to keep versioning on my projects. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940276/how-to-use-svn-without-a-server/2940316#2940316

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's your OS ?
On Windows, TortoiseSVN provides a great client, but also include a full local SVN Server.
Just click right on any empty folder and choose "Create repository here", and you will be able to perform commits and checkouts on this repository.

There is only a little bit limitation : you can only acceed to repository with file:// protocol, no web support (which is perfect for your use).

If you also want http support (LAN or Internet), you can also use VisualSVN Server, very simple to install and setup, and almost free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Svnserve based server](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html):

> Subversion includes Svnserve - a lightweight stand-alone server which
>   uses a custom protocol over an ordinary TCP/IP connection. It is ideal
>   for smaller installations, or where a full blown Apache server cannot
>   be used.

Check the link there are the step to be taken there in order to install it.

Comment: There is no real need to setup svnserve on Windows nowadays (at least for only one developer). You can access repositories over 'file://' and install a SVN bundle like VisualSVN Server. That's enough.